# Create an immutable list from a java.lang.Iterator

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-java-interop, jxpath

I'm using a library ([JXPath](http://commons.apache.org/jxpath)) to query a graph of beans in order to extract matching elements. However, JXPath returns groups of matching elements as an instance of java.lang.Iterator and I'd  rather like to convert it into an immutable scala list. Is there any simpler way of doing than iterating over the iterator and creating a new immutable list at each iteration step ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You might want to rethink the need for a `List`, although it feels very familiar when coming from Java, and List is the default implementation of an immutable `Seq`, it often isn't the best choice of collection.

The operations that list is optimal for are those already available via an iterator (basically taking consecutive head elements and prepending elements).  If an iterator doesn't already give you what you need, then I can pretty much guarantee that a List won't be your best choice - a vector would be more appropriate.

---

Having got that out the way... The recommended technique to convert between Java and Scala collections (since Scala 2.8.1) is via [`scala.collection.JavaConverters`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html).  This gives you more control than `JavaConversions` and avoids some possible implicit conflicts.

You won't have a direct implicit conversion this way.  Instead, you get `asScala` and `asJava` methods pimped onto collections, allowing you to perform the conversions explicitly.

To convert a Java iterator to a Scala iterator:

```
javaIterator.asScala
```

To convert a Java iterator to a Scala List (via the scala iterator):

```
javaIterator.asScala.toList
```

---

You may also want to consider converting `toSeq` instead of `toList`.  In the case of iterators, this'll return a `Stream` - allowing you to retain the lazy behaviour of iterators within the richer `Seq` interface.

**EDIT:**
There's no `toVector` method, but (as Daniel pointed out) there's a `toIndexedSeq` method that will return a `Vector` as the default `IndexedSeq` subclass (just as `List` is the default `Seq`).

```
javaIterator.asScala.toIndexedSeq
```

Comment: Kevin, as your answer is clearly better, I'll delete mine. And I'll definitely look at all the new API introduced in 2.8.1 and 2.9!

Comment: @Jean-Philippe - Do you know how depressing that is?  It shows that I've clearly been burdened with *far* too much Java interop work in my time... Besides, you raised an important point about `TraversableOnce` and `++`; your answer would help some hypothetical future reader who was interested in concatenating a Java collection.

Comment: @Kevin OK, I've reopened it, directing readers to your answer in an edit.

Comment: @Kevin `Vector` is the default implementation of `IndexedSeq`, and there is a `toIndexedSeq`.

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT:** You should probably look at [Kevin Wright's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014881/create-an-immutable-list-from-a-java-lang-iterator/6015315#6015315), which provides a better solution available since Scala 2.8.1, with less implicit magic.

---

You can import the implicit conversions from [`scala.collection.JavaConversions`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/JavaConversions$.html) and then create a new Scala collection seamlessly, e.g. like this:

```
import collection.JavaConversions._
println(List() ++ javaIterator)
```

Your Java iterator is converted to a Scala iterator by `JavaConversions.asScalaIterator`. A Scala iterator with elements of type `A` implements `TraversableOnce[A]`, which is the argument type needed to concatenate collections with `++`.

If you need another collection type, just change `List()` to whatever you need (e.g., `IndexedSeq()` or `collection.mutable.Seq()`, etc.).